# Grouped bar plot in R - 'height' must be a vector or a matrix

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have the following data and I'd like to make a grouped barplot where it shows both total_deaths_per_million and total_tests_per_thousand grouped by location

```
 location total_deaths_per_million total_tests_per_thousand
  <chr>                       <dbl>                    <dbl>
1 Albania                      617.                     150.
2 Denmark                      407.                    2818.
3 Germany                      837.                     524.
4 Russia                       578.                     756.
```

Every time I use barplot it says "'height' must be a vector or a matrix"

Comment: You really need to provide your actual code, not a description of it. Also provide your data with `dput()` not with a table that cannot be easily cut and pasted into R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
  library(tidyverse)
  df <- tribble(~location, ~total_deaths_per_million, ~total_tests_per_thousand,
 "Albania" ,                     617,                     150,
 "Denmark" ,                     407,                    2818,
 "Germany" ,                     837,                     524,
 "Russia"  ,                     578,                     756)

df2 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-location)
barplot(value ~ name + location, data = df2,
        beside = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-location) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(location, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-location) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~location) + coord_flip()
```

[image]